# RFID reader(125kHz) switching between antennas

Tags: arduino, multiplexer, rfid, c++

My arduino application wants multiple separate cards in multiple separate (nearby) locations to be readable at roughly the same time.

I am using a RDM6300 module, with a multiplexer to switch between antennas, and this is slow. (Power down, switch in an antenna, power up, wait long enough to be sure the card would answer if it was there, power down, switch in the next antenna and so on)

There's an RX pin labeled in addition to the TX pin on RDM6300 module, might it be possible to put these things into a mode where I could be queried on demand, with timing I can control?

Should I use another 125kHz RFID reader to accomplish a faster read? [ID-3LA Reader](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ID/ID-3LA.pdf) seems to be a better choice. Did anyone use it in a similar case?
Can I use [ID-3LA Reader](https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Sensors/ID/ID-3LA.pdf) without power down/up when the tags are already available in locations?

Comment: why power down?

Comment: The tags with the RDM6300 module will emit their tags a few times, but at some point the antenna can not provide enough power for the tag to emit again and the flow stops.If I power down/up the RDM6300 it forces "re-energize" of the tag and transmission resumes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It always helps to find the [datasheet](https://elty.pl/upload/download/RFID/RDM630-Spec.pdf) of the parts you use:

[image]

That's from the datasheet.  It says there's two types of reader:

1. Read once, must move card out of range to read again.
2. Read continuously - card data will be returned as long as it can be read.

You seem to have the first type, which is the standard type.

If you want to read continuosly, you'll need to either get the version of the RDM6300 that reads continuously or you'll need to get a different reader.

That it can't read a card more than once has nothing to do with providing enough power.  It has to do with the reader rejecting tags it has already read.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that you change between different antennas using a reed relais, I'm not sure if that's what you do with your multiplexing. At least some RFID readers are fine with disonnecting the antenna mid-run which would save you the time of power-up/power down.

In that case, the reader should return a new tag each time the antenna (& tag) changes. Read time is probably around 32ms per full read-cycle. To avoid catching the tag mid-read, increase it and you can switch through all available antennas quickly.

Depending on how far away your antennas are from each other you could also use multiple readers that are switched on at the same time to get maximum read-speed.